# Zoho CRM SDK - How to trigger a function on load?

Tags: javascript, sdk, onload, zoho

I have created a widget that retrieves the Current User details of the current ZOHO CRM logged in person.

I have a button that takes the Email of the Current User and filters a database based on the retrieved Email.

I currently have this working by clicking on a button, however I am trying to have this function trigger when the page is loaded.

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <div style = "width:100%;margin:auto;">
       <button type="button" style="margin:20px;cursor: pointer;background-color: blue;color:white;padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px;width:200;" id="wOpen"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Refresh My Tasks</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var currentUserEmail;
$(document).ready(function() {

    ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad", function(onloadData) {
        data1 = onloadData;
    });

    $("#wOpen").click(function() {

    ZOHO.CRM.CONFIG.getCurrentUser().then(function(data){
      console.log(data.users[0].email);
      currentUserEmail = data.users[0].email;
      document.getElementById('iframe1').src = 'https://creatorapp.zohopublic.com.au/ozeitaus/tasks/report-embed/Copy_of_Tasks_Report/J7qC6AS7Jzk8sNJabbTV6jrrWzz4GhSTJHQWkspmm2Sjm7zWNECD2qUWwOdOaDkqGZO5GOT87bufbUqMDRCpQhyD0y0JazH1P4fv?Status=Completed&Status_op=19&MainTaskOwnerEmail='+ currentUserEmail;


})
    });
    ZOHO.embeddedApp.init();

});
</script>
<iframe id="iframe1" height='500px' width='100%' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true' scrolling='auto' src=''></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of fetching the user details separately after the PageLoad event, fetch it inside that function itself.

*Sample Code (Not tested)*

```js
ZOHO.embeddedApp.on("PageLoad", function(data) {
  //.....
  ZOHO.CRM.CONFIG.getCurrentUser()
    .then(function(userdata){
        console.log(userdata.users[0].email);
        currentUserEmail = userdata.users[0].email;
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
     });
  ///......
});
ZOHO.embeddedApp.init();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Move the contents of the click function to the on PageLoad callback

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29824282)